# HTML colour of button displaying differently on mobile device

Tags: html, css, button, mobile, background-color

I have a mobile website which uses the #0096D6 shade of blue for some buttons. My problem is that the colour shows up differently on certain pages on the same device even though the colour is set as the same.I was wondering if anyone knows what could be causing this?

Here is how I have declared the colour of the button:

```
.button {
    background-color: #0096D6;
}
```

Here are the two colours which show up:

Expected colour across all pages:

[image: Expected colour]

Displayed colour on some pages:

[image: the wrong colour]

As you can see there is not a huge difference in the two colours but I was wondering if anyone knows why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: did you opened these pictures in graphic program and picked hexadecimal representation ( #ffffff etc. ) ? is the same?

Comment: Yes I opened them both in Windows Picture Viewer

Comment: I think problem width your code,`.button {
    background-color: #0096D6 !important;
}` use like this and check again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devices don't interpret the color different. Its the build-in screen who causes the problem.

In fact its impossible to guarantee that **all** devices show *exact* the same color!

There are (hardware)tools to calibrate displays to a standard but with tons of different devices not under your control you can't ensure they show all the same color!

Even if you use images the colors could be slightly different!

Comment: I was thinking this could be the problem alright but wanted to get other people's input, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry just got an update there. The problem is actually that this colour change happens on the same device but on different pages. Both pages are set to use the same colour on the button though. Do you know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

if hex representation is the same, then colours are the same and problem lies in LCD display. 
It may depend on brightness of your device that is different than your other device.